# What database does Apache Nutch use for storing URLs?

Tags: nutch

I tried to look into its dependencies (see [here](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/ivy/ivy.xml)) but I fail to figure what it uses for storing URLs and handling the progress of the crawl. Judging by the tutorial requirements (see [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/NutchTutorial#NutchTutorial-Requirements)) it doesn't need any 3rd party system, like some SQL database.

So what does it use?

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nutch 1.x stores the data in Hadoop [MapFile](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/MapFile.html)s and [SequenceFile](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile.html)s.  Apache Nutch is a batch-based crawler and the data is

- either write-once/read-many as for the segments created and filled in every crawl cycle
- or rewritten when new data is added: the "CrawlDb" which holds the URLs and status information (fetch status and date, signature / checksum, score, metadata)

Nutch 2.x (retired) put all data into a single "web table" - with scale-up and distribution delegated to big data stores (HBase, etc.) via [Apache Gora](https://gora.apache.org/).